# Equivalent Definitions of Field Trace of Galois Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, galois-extensions, trace-map, field-trace

When studying trace and norm of finite Galois extensions, I stumbled upon two (for Galois extensions) equivalent definitions.

1. $Tr_{L|K}(a) = tr(\phi_a)$ with $\phi_a: L \to L, x \mapsto ax$
2. $Tr_{L|K}(a) = \sum_{\sigma \in Gal(L|K)} \sigma(a)$

Could someone explain to me why those are equivalent? I'm having a hard time seeing the connection. Thank you a lot!!

Comment: And, what is *your* definition?

Comment: There are two relevant polynomials: the characteristic polynomial of the $K$-linear map $\phi_a$ and the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$. These, respectively, contain information about the first and second definition of the trace you wrote. Can you find a connection between these polynomials?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop I don t really know how to calculate the characteristic polynomial of $\phi_a$.. The minimal polynomial of a over K should be some polynomial of degree [L:K] but I feel like I am lacking information to write some concrete polynomials. Could you maybe help a little more? I feel like I need some more help/ explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @azif00 We did not officially define trace and norm of an element of a galois extension (we skipped that in our lecture), I just stumbled upon it when reading through my algebra book.

Comment: Start with the restriction of $\phi_a$ to $K(a)$. Do you know a basis for $K(a)/K$? I think it's reasonable to compute the characteristic polynomial in this extension. To compute it for the whole extension $L/K$, how can you take your basis for $K(a)/K$ and get one for $L/K$? You should end up with something block diagonal.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop a basis of K/K(a) should be {1, a^2, ..., a^n} where n is the degree of the minimal polynomial of a. We have for the characteristic polynomial char: $char(\phi_a’)(X)=det(X*Id-\phi_a’)$ where $\phi_a’$ is the matrix representing our k linear map: $K(a)\rightarrow K(a), z->az = z_0a + z_1a^2 + \dots + z_{n-1}a^n = (z_{n-1} z_1 ... z_{n-2})^T$ in our basis. So the Matrix is the Permutation Matrix that shifts the elements of a vector z. So then I have the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: This is actually only some side reading for a presentation I’ll have to give, and I thought it would be interesting to know. But I think I won’t have time to study that in depth anymore unfortunately :( so maybe do you know a link where (1)=>(2) is shown, so that I can provide that for people interested in the proof?

Comment: I think you mean to end the basis at $a^{n-1}$ and your characteristic polynomial calculation is off. The ladt column of that matrix won't agree with a permutation matrix. Anyways, any Galois theory reference will probably contain it. For instance, look at proposition 1.3.3 [here](http://math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/algnum.pdf)